A property of canonical singularity
Let $X$ be a normal variety with only one singularity at $x$ and $(X,x)$ is a canonical singularity i.e. $(X.x)$ satisfies $(i)$ and $(ii)$.
$(i)$ $(X,x)$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ Goreinstein singularity.
$(ii)$ For any resolution $f:Y \rightarrow X$, we can write $K_Y=f^*K_X+\sum_{i=1}^r m_iE_i$  with $m_i\geqq 0$

How can I  prove that for any resolution $f:Y\rightarrow X$ and $m\in
> \mathbb{Z}_{\geqq 0}$, $f_*\mathcal{O}(mK_Y)\cong \mathcal{O}(mK_X)$?

I don't know even what is a morphism.
Motivation. I want to show the unique ness of "canonical resolution"
A resolution of  $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is called canonical resolution if
(i) $Y$ has at worst canonical singularity.
(ii) $K_Y$ is $f$ ample.
My strategy is this.
Let $f_i:Y_i\rightarrow X$ be two canonical resolution.
Make two common resolution $g_1:X\rightarrow Y_1$ and $g_2:X\rightarrow Y_2$.
From (ii), we get $Y_i\cong$ Proj($\oplus_{m\geqq 0}{f_i}*\mathcal{O}(mK_{Y_i})$).
So if we can show ${g_i}_*\mathcal{O}(mK_{X})\cong \mathcal{O}(mK_{Y_i})$,  we can show $Y_1\cong Y_2\cong $Proj($\oplus_{m\geqq 0}{g_1}_*{f_1}_*\mathcal{O}(mK_{Y_i})$)

Probably, you intended to write $K_Y=f^*K_X+\sum_{i=1}^r m_iE_i$ and the $a_i$ are $m_i$?

Do you really mean for all $m $ or big enough? Since $K_X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier it's multiple for big enough $m$ becomes Cartier, so invertible. But as $X$ is normal, you can use Hartog's argument on the base as $x$ has codim $\ge 2$ (if your $X$ is not a curve)

@user267839
Thanks. You are right.

@user267839
I mean for all non negative m.
Could you see my motivation added in the question.

@user267839
Hartog's argument might be used for my porpose too.
Thanks.

so far I understand you correctly, you only want that projs are isomorphic,right? It is well known that if you start with a graded ring $A=\oplus_{n=0}A_n$ then for arbitrary two positive integers $ r,s>0$ the proj of another graded ring $R=\oplus_{n=0}R_n$
declared by (1) $R_0:=A_0$
,(2) $R_d:=0$
for $d<r$
and (3) $R_k:=A_{ks}$ is isomorphic to it (think about Veronesse embedding). So maybe it suffice to twist with big enough $m$ (and it's multiples, such that all $msK$ become invertible, and then take proj of the new graded ring obtained via this Veronese trick. Maybe this helps?

Amazing. Thanks for a lot of new technique for me.
But I have some question.
Where do we need the fact that $X$ has at worst cannonical singulairty?

In order to apply Hartog's argument, $f_*O_\mathcal{O}(mK_Y)$ and $\mathcal{O}(mK_X)$ need to be reflexive, right?
Can we check?

About where canonicality of the singularity goes in I have not idea. But concerning your last remark I would argue easier (in fact without using reflexitivity; but maybe I'm missing something): For big enough $m$ is $mK_X$ invertible. As $f$ induces isom $Y-f^{-1}(x) \cong X-x$ of regular schemes (...as you wrote that it is singular only in x) the pushforward functor $f_*$ maps outside $f^{-1}(x)$ as induced by an iso canonical sheaf to canonical, right? Then we have two isomorphic locally free sheaves over $X-x$. Doesn't locally freeness + normality suffice to apply Hartogs?

essentially what I'm going to use is that by nature of canonicality if $g: X \to Y$ is an iso of regular schemes, then $f_*$ maps canonical sheaf to canonical (... of course modulo isom class, as canonicality is defined up to isom)

This essentially follows from Claim 2.3.1, p. 39 of
J. Kollár, S. Kovács: Singularities of the Minimal Model Program, Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 200 (2013).
The Authors prove the result for $m=1$, but the same proof works without modifications for every $m \geq 1$. Compare also with Claim 2.3.2 (same page), Proposition 2.17 (p. 48) and Proposition 2.18 (p. 49).
The last result, applied with $S=X, \, p_X=\text{id}_X$, $\Delta=\Delta_Y=\emptyset$, gives precisely the statement you need.
